# Using Firestore with offline persistence - Desktop (web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Offline persistence in Firestore enables the browser to store records that were not uploaded to the server (offline) even after the session was closed (Browser exit)

Please see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

However, firestore does not offer any officially supported way to clear the Chace when a user logs out from his session. Please refer to: https://youtu.be/qGAIimfrBB4?t=257

Recently they released the function ***clearPersistence***, but they clearly state that is not meant for security reasons and recommend to disable Persistence if security is an important factor for you. Please see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#clearPersistence()

> Note: clearPersistence() is primarily intended to help write reliable
> tests that use Cloud Firestore. It uses an efficient mechanism for
> dropping existing data but does not attempt to securely overwrite or
> otherwise make cached data unrecoverable. For applications that are
> sensitive to the disclosure of cached data in between user sessions,
> we strongly recommend not enabling persistence at all.

I want to understand better what's the security hole with using "ClearPersistence" on logout of the user.

Anyone experienced with that? Any other working solution that enables you to remove all the Firestore cache after a logout?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that your code will run in the browser (or any other client). For example: a malicious user can take the configuration data from your application, and call the API to get access to the same data in your project, but then store it wherever they want.

Another malicious user might prevent the app from clearing the local cache, or quickly copy the local cache file to another location to have a copy before it is cleared.

And these are just two if the simplest examples. The simple fact is that you should assume that any data that exists/persists on the client can be seen by any user who has access to that client.

Comment: Let's assume clearPersistence was called before a malicious user had the chance to do any of this. Will he still have access to the user data? Even if clearPersistence  ran successfully? Is it even possible to run clearPersistance after a firestore session initialized? I am not worried about users having access to their data while still logged in. I am worried about them having access to it after logout.

Comment: Your answer talks about security holes with chacing in general, and it's not specific to security holes with running ClearPersistence function after user sign out.